# Reading C structures in Python with ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I'm using ctypes to call foreign functions in Python3.

The C function is supposed to return the pointer to the structure:

```
struct sLinkedList {
    void* data;
    struct sLinkedList* next;
 };

typedef struct sLinkedList* LinkedList;
```

And the function as it is defined in C is as follows.

```
LinkedList IedConnection_getServerDirectory (IedConnection  self, IedClientError *  error, bool     getFileNames )
```

So I have my Python3 code as follows:

```
from ctypes import *

...

class LinkedList(Structure):
    pass

LinkedList._fields_ = [("data",c_void_p), ("next",  POINTER(LinkedList))]

...

IedConnection_getServerDirectory=dlllib.IedConnection_getServerDirectory
IedConnection_getServerDirectory.argtypes=[c_void_p, c_void_p]
IedConnection_getServerDirectory.restype = c_int
LogicalDevicesPtr = IedConnection_getServerDirectory(IedConnection,iedClientError)
```

The IedConnection parameter is retrieved by other function as pointer, and I'm pretty sure it works fine. Also I can see that function itself works fine (it initiates communications, that could be seen in Wireshark).

Then I try to get the information as result of function:

```
LogicalDevicesList_p = cast(LogicalDevicesPtr,POINTER(LinkedList))

LogicalDeviceList = LogicalDevicesList_p.contents
```

This lines passes and the following line fails:

```
Rdata = LogicalDeviceList.data
```

with "Segmentation fault: 11"

I suppose the problem if with types definitions, but I have no idea where the mistake is. Could anyone help?

Comment: Why are you defining your Python `LinkedList` to match the C `struct sLinkedList` instead of the C `LinkedList`?

Comment: And why did you set the `argtypes` and `restype` of the function on the Python side to something completely unlike how the C function is actually defined?

Answer (score 2):

Well, looks like i've solved it by myself:

```
IedConnection_getServerDirectory.restype = c_int
```

is incorrect and shall was changed to:

```
IedConnection_getServerDirectory.restype = c_void_p
```

**And it started working fine already.**

But additionally I've added third argument to function call to make it more neat:

```
IedConnection_getServerDirectory.argtypes=[c_void_p, c_void_p, c_bool]
LogicalDevicesPtr = IedConnection_getServerDirectory(IedConnection,iedClientError,c_bool(False))
```